# How to maintain SVG's wave shape across all screen sizes

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm using [getwaves.io](https://getwaves.io/) to create SVG waves for a website. I want to add the SVG on top of the screen right below the navbar. The problem is as the screen becomes smaller, the SVG loses its original shape. How can I make sure the SVG looks exactly the same on all different screen sizes?

By the way, I had to add `style="height: 100%"` to the SVG, otherwise it just disappears on smaller screens.

```html
<svg style="height: 100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path fill="#000" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L48,149.3C96,171,192,213,288,224C384,235,480,213,576,192C672,171,768,149,864,138.7C960,128,1056,128,1152,154.7C1248,181,1344,235,1392,261.3L1440,288L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"></path>
</svg>
```

**UPDATE:**

If I remove the navbar and add `width: 100%`, it works. But, with the navbar it looks like part of the SVG goes under the navbar as the screen becomes smaller.

Comment: remove the height

Comment: @enxaneta As I explained in the question, it will become smaller and smaller until it disappear on the smallest screen size. With the height, at least there's a wave, but with a different shape.

Comment: Fix on 100% width, not height. Use also min-width:100%

Comment: @MarkusZeller That didn't work. Again, look at my comment above about the height.

Comment: Then give a min-height or place a wrapper around.

Comment: @MarkusZeller That doesn't work either.

Comment: Works, when I copy the code to answer and resize screen to very small.

Comment: give it a min-height combined with preserveAspectRatio="none" <svg style="height: 100%;min-height:20vh;width:100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320" preserveAspectRatio="none">

Comment: @th31 That helped a little. The SVG has the same shape now, but it still loses its height until on the smaller screen it looks like half of the shape is below the navbar.

Comment: By the way, this works if I remove the navbar.

Comment: OK, this had nothing to do with the SVG. I just had to add `padding-top` to the `body`, because of the fixed navbar.

Comment: @ataravati I was doing the same thing, I even tried to make it a png image and then made it div background but the problem is when resizing only half of the SVG is seen, but I want an SVG that will resize its width without losing its height basically dynamically changing its shape. Have you (@ataravati) found a solution to this?

Comment: @ataravati Hey, hopping in real quick to check whether I solved your issue or do I need to ameliorate my skills?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is set the width of the svg to 100%, that way it will stretch to the container's width.

I provided an example:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-container {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 60rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-container">
    <header class="content">
        <h1>Logo</h1>
        <nav>Items...</nav>
    </header>
</div>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
    <path fill="#000" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,128L48,149.3C96,171,192,213,288,224C384,235,480,213,576,192C672,171,768,149,864,138.7C960,128,1056,128,1152,154.7C1248,181,1344,235,1392,261.3L1440,288L1440,0L1392,0C1344,0,1248,0,1152,0C1056,0,960,0,864,0C768,0,672,0,576,0C480,0,384,0,288,0C192,0,96,0,48,0L0,0Z"></path>
</svg>
<main class="content">
    <p>
        <span>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos assumenda laudantium quo incidunt eius facere cumque neque, vel delectus et, sapiente natus? Qui quas ratione maiores quam atque quis consequuntur.</span>
        <span>Veniam inventore dolores molestias cum rerum culpa labore, amet perspiciatis ut ipsa. Totam adipisci, eius illo, beatae aperiam ab aut, amet ex dolore saepe minus. Architecto enim porro ab aliquam.</span>
        <span>Dolorum vero placeat ratione cupiditate! Inventore laboriosam ratione sapiente sit dolores, voluptatem fugit tempora qui vel ad corrupti. Eveniet nostrum itaque ullam doloremque omnis aliquid sapiente quibusdam alias incidunt nam!</span>
        <span>Dignissimos facere voluptatem, non deserunt quo labore nihil distinctio voluptatum facilis doloremque, quasi magnam asperiores recusandae adipisci laudantium at error! Ducimus laborum ut officia eaque voluptate reprehenderit corrupti dolor voluptatem?</span>
        <span>Inventore aliquid at, excepturi enim accusamus eaque quia velit, nesciunt laudantium animi ea praesentium blanditiis numquam obcaecati sequi modi aperiam! Sapiente, velit pariatur itaque aspernatur consectetur neque voluptas. Ad, voluptatum?</span>
        <span>In vitae doloremque cupiditate, ad sapiente consectetur odit, enim aspernatur aut earum deleniti vel nobis soluta inventore dolores, similique suscipit officia nisi amet? Quae ab cumque corporis hic odio error?</span>
        <span>Blanditiis ipsum delectus id praesentium! Nam deserunt eum, quia tenetur voluptatum ipsam fugit sed nesciunt non, sunt distinctio provident, rem iusto magni cumque officia veritatis soluta nostrum. Modi, blanditiis dignissimos!</span>
        <span>Non consequuntur debitis velit obcaecati. Aspernatur animi tempora reprehenderit nam cum. Iure quas debitis architecto, placeat deserunt laboriosam, libero iste similique, id ea laudantium dolore ipsam odio illo consectetur voluptatibus.</span>
        <span>Dolore, fugiat blanditiis porro libero quam hic nostrum qui? Ab exercitationem magni eius repellat blanditiis harum maxime ipsum? Beatae perspiciatis numquam asperiores facilis? Totam optio sapiente reprehenderit facilis quam sed.</span>
        <span>Explicabo amet dolore laboriosam corporis facere laborum sit enim. Dolore tempora adipisci, unde aut ullam ut molestias iste, ducimus dolorum error, iusto quaerat? Eveniet itaque sunt, quam commodi minima accusamus.</span>
        <span>Impedit, perferendis ullam aspernatur amet omnis numquam eos ipsum sapiente consequatur sit dolore eaque nostrum eius repellat sint earum dignissimos neque quam maiores, voluptate magnam at. Nulla ea voluptatem ducimus.</span>
        <span>Ullam, fuga voluptatibus, cupiditate autem, et cumque quae quia rerum corrupti dolores dolore similique aut consequuntur ipsa quaerat ut deserunt velit dolorem voluptate quas harum quod porro possimus magni? Dolores.</span>
        <span>Et quidem enim doloremque officiis aliquid repellat optio minus, fuga, quo beatae in, suscipit non aperiam est rerum numquam vitae culpa nesciunt dolores consectetur fugiat perferendis facere asperiores. Iste, sed?</span>
    </p>
</main>
```

Comment: I couldn't pinpoint my mistake, but this worked for me so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use **Viewport Units** like `vw` for **width** and `vh` for **height** instead of `px`, `%`, `rem` or `em` to make your webpage/website responsive so that it looks same on all screens.

**For Example:-** `width: 100%;` is equal to `width: 100vw;` *and* `height: 100%;` is equal to `height: 100vh;`.

Try it, it will surely work but if it doesn't let me know in the comments, I will try my best to assist you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a way to test this with the navbar anymore. But, without the navbar it works.

Comment: @ataravati I didn't understood your comment, please clarify it so that I could assist you better and thanks for upvoting my answer, it means a lot to me.

Comment: I decided not use the SVG, so I don't have the code anymore to test.